# touchesBegan Event Stops Firing After a Lot of Scrolling

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a series of UITableViews displayed in a horizontal ScrollView. Inside each tableview, each TableViewCell consists of 2 thumbnail tiles which represent a detail view. I am using `touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to catch when one of the tiles has been tapped. From there, I am pushing a detail view onto the NavigationController and showing a different screen. This interaction works when the initial view is loaded. However, if you scroll any of the tableviews quickly up and down, the touchesBegan event stops firing. No memory warnings are received during this time.

Here is the code I'm using inside of the view controller which receives the tap (a small tile inside of the tableviewcell:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"Touched received on ArticleTileViewController");
    ArticleViewController *vc = [[ArticleViewController alloc] initWithArticleData:self.articleDataArray];
    ProjectAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ProjectAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    [appDelegate.navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]; 
}
```

EDIT: I've also tried the same thing with touchesEnded, same behavior results.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by switching to using the UITapGestureRecognizer. Implementation was quick and easy!!